# BLE Advertising data on iOS peripheral

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am about to start developing an iOS app which depends on being able to send small pieces of data over a Bluetooth LE advertisement (so the iOS device is the peripheral).

Reading the following [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/PerformingCommonPeripheralRoleTasks/PerformingCommonPeripheralRoleTasks.html) I stumbled upon the following:

> That said, only two of the keys are supported for peripheral manager
>   objects: CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey and
>   CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey.

Does this mean I am unable to specify what data is advertised, and that I am limited to the devices name (a constant) essentially?

I was under the impression I was able to advertise roughly 28 bytes of data at my discretion. I did not want to start a major project if it turns out advertising custom data is not possible.

Comment: What is your Central device ? make sure UUID in both central and peripheral are same.

Comment: They will be the same. However I'm not clear on whether a custom advertisement is possible.

Comment: Where in the documentation?

Answer (score -2):

Answer is - You can! If you read further through the documentation you would know how to do it.

Once you are done reading [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/PerformingCommonPeripheralRoleTasks/PerformingCommonPeripheralRoleTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH4-SW1) and [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/PerformingCommonCentralRoleTasks/PerformingCommonCentralRoleTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH3-SW1) documentation, I would advise you to go through this line by line implementation of Central-Peripheral combo [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-7-sdk-core-bluetooth-practical-lesson--mobile-20741).

Here is a sneak peek of how to do it (writing data by peripheral triggers `peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:` on central counterpart):

```
- (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral central:(CBCentral *)central didSubscribeToCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic {

    _dataToSend = [_textView.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    _sendDataIndex = 0;

    [self sendData];
}

- (void)sendData {

    static BOOL sendingEOM = NO;

    // end of message?
    if (sendingEOM) {
        BOOL didSend = [self.peripheralManager updateValue:[@"EOM" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] forCharacteristic:self.transferCharacteristic onSubscribedCentrals:nil];

        if (didSend) {
            // It did, so mark it as sent
            sendingEOM = NO;
        }
        // didn't send, so we'll exit and wait for peripheralManagerIsReadyToUpdateSubscribers to call sendData again
        return;
    }

    // We're sending data
    // Is there any left to send?
    if (self.sendDataIndex >= self.dataToSend.length) {
        // No data left.  Do nothing
        return;
    }

    // There's data left, so send until the callback fails, or we're done.
    BOOL didSend = YES;

    while (didSend) {
        // Work out how big it should be
        NSInteger amountToSend = self.dataToSend.length - self.sendDataIndex;

        // Can't be longer than 20 bytes
        if (amountToSend > NOTIFY_MTU) amountToSend = NOTIFY_MTU;

        // Copy out the data we want
        NSData *chunk = [NSData dataWithBytes:self.dataToSend.bytes+self.sendDataIndex length:amountToSend];

        didSend = [self.peripheralManager updateValue:chunk forCharacteristic:self.transferCharacteristic onSubscribedCentrals:nil];

        // If it didn't work, drop out and wait for the callback
        if (!didSend) {
            return;
        }

        NSString *stringFromData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:chunk encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Sent: %@", stringFromData);

        // It did send, so update our index
        self.sendDataIndex += amountToSend;

        // Was it the last one?
        if (self.sendDataIndex >= self.dataToSend.length) {

            // Set this so if the send fails, we'll send it next time
            sendingEOM = YES;

            BOOL eomSent = [self.peripheralManager updateValue:[@"EOM" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] forCharacteristic:self.transferCharacteristic onSubscribedCentrals:nil];

            if (eomSent) {
                // It sent, we're all done
                sendingEOM = NO;
                NSLog(@"Sent: EOM");
            }

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code sends data via a characteristic, not as part of the advertisement